# Inserting a datetime value from php into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column with datetime datatype called 'updated_at' in a mysql table,where i want the current date and time.Im trying to insert a record into the mysql table from php,as follows:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table (service_name,service_status,service_comment,user_name,updated_at) VALUES($service_name,$service_status,$service_comment,$user_name,$updated_at) ")
```

$updated_at is defined as follows:

```
$updated_at = date("D, d M Y H:i:s O");
```

But the insert is not taking place. Any way to fix this problem ?

Please help
Thank You

Comment: datetime field format is mile away from "D, d M Y H:i:s O" one

Comment: however, it's not the only fault here...

Comment: @James In addition to what @Col says, you need to wrap the values in quotes.  `'$updated_at'`...

Comment: Thanks for the reply col. What change should i make to the code ?

Comment: Inline values? C'mon, you're asking for trouble. Use parametrized query, it'll take care of quotes for you.

Comment: @vartec strictly speaking, parametrized query has nothing to do with quotes

Comment: @Shrapnel: bind_param() takes care of properly quoting and escaping parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [a date format that MySQL understands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html):

```
$updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO my_table (service_name,service_status,service_comment,user_name,updated_at) VALUES($service_name,$service_status,$service_comment,$user_name,NOW())
```

For mode details, see [reference for NOW() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

Comment: do not reproduce the OP's mistakes in your answer, but rather correct them

Answer (score 0):

date('Y-m-d H:i:s') OR use NOW() OR set default value to collumn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP